# Trying to run terrier.bat file through window cmd

Tags: java, web-crawler, data-retrieval

I am trying to follow the terrier quick start guide but am facing an issue, I try to run the bin\terrier.bat on windows cmd but I get the following

"Error: Could not find or load main class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:"

I am in the terrier directory which is in my downloads folder, I have java version 11, my system path environment variables are all set. According to the guide it should show me the terrier version and all the commands available. Here is a link to the quick start guide https://github.com/terrier-org/terrier-core/blob/5.x/doc/quickstart_experiments.md

Comment: Pretty sure the error message you posted is incomplete. Look again and you'll see the name of the class that it couldn't find, which is an important clue here.

Comment: C:\Users\marve\Downloads\terrier-project-5.5>bin\terrier.bat
Error: Could not find or load main class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

this is the full thing

Comment: Looks like whatever executable the bat file is running is stepping on the real error message. I'd look to see if a real Java Stack trace is being saved someplace and start there.